# Google Tag Manager increases Largest Contentful Paint. How to load it after page fully load?

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager, google-pagespeed

I'm having a very simple page includes bootstrap. The page score in pagespeed is 99 and LCP is 2.0 but when I add Google tag manager script, page scored turned into 85 and LCP turned into 4.2

Is there anyway to load that script after page fully loaded to prevent reducing the score and increasing LCP

```
<script defer src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx-1"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-xxx-1');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You see where you have `<script type="application/javascript">`, add a defer rule.
So it becomes `<script defer type="application/javascript">`.
This way it will run that piece at the end. Though to be honest, there isn't a lot going on there.

Comment: Added it but nothing changed

Comment: inline javascript can't be defered using a defer attribute.  Instead you need to wrap it in an event like dom content loaded.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the `async` attribute, it should already be the default https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gtagjs :

```
<script async src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-xxx-1"></script>
<script type="application/javascript">
    window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
    gtag('js', new Date());
    gtag('config', 'UA-xxx-1');
</script>
```

Comment: didn't work. score is low and LCP is very high. loading the script after fully page load will keep the score high and LCP low

Comment: Can you update with results from light house?

Comment: score 85 and LCP 4.2

Comment: Do you get the same scores with this? https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/